# .NET Interop: How to get returned string (not null terminated) from unmanaged DLL in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop, marshalling

I defined a function in C DLL library.

```
__declspec(dllexport) void* GetText();
```

It will return a string which is dynamically allocated from heap memory (And GlobalAlloc is used here for allocating memory). Note that the returned string is **not** *null-terminated*.

---

Then at C# side I tried two methods to declare the function

```
[DllImport("D:\\ca\\TextAccessLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern String GetText();
```

When calling above method, the application will crash without any exception thrown.

```
[DllImport("D:\\ca\\TextAccessLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern IntPtr GetText();

ptr = GetText();
string text = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ptr, 1000);
```

And calling this method will return incorrect string. Checked the real bytes by using Marshal.Copy, I found the bytes value is not same as the value in DLL library. (I think it's caused by *Virtual Memory*, C# process cannot access memory space of the DLL directly)

(Don't mind the string length, I hard coded it to 1000 for ease)

---

This is the C++ code and the memory value of the string when debugging (It's a Console Application but not the original DLL, because Console Application is easy to debug. But the DLL code is same as this one except the logging part).
[image]
Following is the original DLL code

```
__declspec(dllexport) char* GetText(){
    VTHDOC hDoc = NULL;
    VTHTEXT hText = VTHDOC_INVALID;
    DAERR da_err = NULL;
    DAERR ta_err = NULL;
    DAERR read_err = NULL;
    char *buf = (char*)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, 1000);
    DWORD real_size;


    DAInitEx(SCCOPT_INIT_NOTHREADS, OI_INIT_DEFAULT);
    da_err = DAOpenDocument(&hDoc, 2, "D:\\1TB.doc", 0);
    ta_err = TAOpenText(hDoc, &hText);
    read_err = TAReadFirst(hText, (VTLPBYTE)buf, 1000, &real_size);

    return buf;
}
```

---

But at C# side the bytes are not same as C++ side
[image]

You can see the first byte in C++ is 0, but it's 200 for C# (decimal)

---

Another thing to note: if I return a const string(e.g. "AASSDD") directly in DLL code, C# side will get the correct string

Comment: *Why* isn't the string zero-terminated? How will you know its length?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This string is generated by another text extraction library which is used to extract text from PDF, Word, Excel, etc. files. And this library forced the generated string to be not null-terminated. 


Now I hard coded the string length to 1000 for ease, later I will set the length as **out** parameter.

Comment: You must use `IntPtr` and you must somehow measure the returned array length.   Then use Marshal.Copy().  Then fret a great deal how the memory for that array is going to be released.  Nobody here can possibly tell you how to measure the array length.  Your are pinvoking broken code, that never makes it less broken.

Comment: @HansPassant I edited my post to use Marshal.Copy() now, but the bytes I got in C# is not same as C++ side..

Comment: @MarkMa Don't use `GMEM_MOVEABLE`, use `GMEM_FIXED`. The `GMEM_MOVEABLE` doesn't return a real pointer, but only an handle.

Comment: @xanatos Thanks for the correction, I updated post using your suggestion. But I found the bytes value in C# and C++ are still not same..

Comment: I have strong doubts that *anything* can begin with 55 `\0` bytes (see C++ side)... And you haven't shown the `GetText()` code.

Comment: @xanatos Yes this is a Console Application to test the C++ functionality, because I cannot debug the DLL directly. But the code in DLL is same as this one.

Comment: @MarkMa And are you sure it is a cdecl and not a stdcall? Because the wrong calling convention could explain the problem

Comment: @xanatos I didn't define the calling convention explicitly, so I think it should be cdecl (I remember the default calling convention is cdecl, maybe I'm wrong.) And I have pasted the DLL code into the question, could you check if there's anything wrong within it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @xanatos And I tried setting calling convention to stdcall in C# as you said, but the first byte is still not `\0`, really weird..

Comment: @MarkMa Note that you *can* debug a DLL: if you have the DLL in the same solution, in the C# project, right click, properties, Debug, Enable Native Code Debugging

Comment: Your code as written is correct. I've done a test with a similar code (see the description https://ideone.com/45o8wU) and it works as it should. So the problem could be: A) You are corrupting the memory in the calls to all the DA*/TA* methods. This would explain the strange output you have (**I haven't ever seen a file that starts with 55 `\0`**) or B) you are calling an old version of `CA\TextAccessLibrary.dll`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way. Marshaling of `string` works only for null-terminated strings (or for BSTR, if you specify some options). You can:

```
[DllImport("D:\\ca\\TextAccessLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern IntPtr GetText();
```

But from there, it isn't clear how the C# program should know the length of the string.

The various `Marshal` methods of C# handle BSTR (that have internally their length) or `NUL` terminated strings.

Comment: Sorry I'm using this declaration style as you said in the second C# DLL method declaration. (I copied wrong code it's corrected now..)

Comment: @MarkMa The `void*` **is** the same as the `IntPtr`, the only problem is with `Marshal.PtrToStringAuto` that requires a null terminated string.

Comment: @MarkMa And in general it is better if you use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` if you know that the string is Ansi, because the `Auto` version probably uses Unicode.

Comment: I updated my post and use Marsal.Copy to copy bytes from IntPtr now, but the bytes seems incorrect (because it's not same as C++ side)

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, it works for null-terminated strings only, in the following way:

C# part, declaration:

```
[DllImport("myDll.dll", EntryPoint = "myString", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = false)]
extern private static string myString(out int size);
```

C# part, usage:

```
        int size;
        string s = myString(out size);
```

C++ part:

```
char* myString(int* size)
{
    *size = 20;
    char* strg = (char*)::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, *size);
    memset(strg, 0x3f, *size); //preset with a questionmark
    for (int i=0; i < 9; i++)
        strg[i] = 0x40 + i;
    strg[*size -1] = 0; //limit the maximum string length
    return strg;
}
```

And the obtained C# string:
"@ABCDEFGH??????????", value of size: 20

A treatment of the issue may be found [here](https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/returning-strings-from-a-c-api/)

Comment: This method will cause the application crash without any exception thrown in Visual Studio (any idea why no exception is thrown?)

Comment: Works like a charm with me! VS2008, .NET3.5, in Debug as well as in Release Mode. Perhaps you have another issue when interfacing C#/C++? I will give it a try in VS2013 as well. BTW, when doing it wrong (e.g. with a malloc instead of a GlobalAlloc) an exception is thrown here.

Comment: Perhaps another possible issue: In the title, you mention a C DLL being called from C#. In your code, you show a _tmain function. A DLL usually does not have a _tmain function.

Comment: @Mark Ma: I just made a bare-bones project with VS2013 and .NET 4.0: It works in 32Bit, in 64Bit in both Debug and Release mode. In Release Mode, it works also when allocating the memory with malloc instead of GlobalAlloc. With the malloc in Debug mode, it crashes with an exception im mscorlib.dll, which cannot be catched (I was mistaken with my last comment with respect to the exception). In case you are interested, I could email you that project for a comparison with your own code.

Comment: My email is 519329064@qq.com, thanks a lot for your help!